# How can edit deployed laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have website that create from laravel. I want to do some customization to that. Project files does not have in my local machine. I have files that deployed to my hosting. I need to help for edit it. How can i do it

Comment: Download the files, edit them and re-upload them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply download your files from remote host, edit anything you want and re-upload them. 
It's good to remember that you don't need to download the `vendor` folder,
since you can use `composer install` when you have the files in your local machine.
After finishing the update, upload the files back to the server, and, if you have ssh access, run `composer update`, to update your dependencies. If you can't use ssh, just overwrite the vendor folder on remote host.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you are using a [IaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_a_service)

**First:**

You can do it by accessing via ssh with [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/), if you're completely sure what to change. Anyways it is the easy way but not the best one.

**Second:** (What I suggest)

You can use a version-control system, via Github. You can use to upload your local changes and pull them in your deployed server.

**Third**

You can use [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)  to tranfer your files to the server fia FTP.